# How to fetch Data at .run() using $http Synchronous call before executing the controller in anjularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, synchronous

At the `.run()` I am trying to fetch data from URL to be used later as a part of header for every request.

So at the `.run()` function, I am using the `$http.get` to fetch that data (generate token) and assigned to global value.

The problem the `$http.get` will return the data even after controller is initialized so , how I can fetch this data (token) from URL (synchronously) and then execute the controller 's initialization. 
here is my code :

```
var appc=angular.module('app', []);
appc.value('mytoken', '');
appc.value('RESTUrl', 'http://localhost/token');
appc.run(function ($http, RESTUrl, $q, mytoken) {



$http.get(RESTUrl +'?user=currss').then (function (response)
{
    mytoken = response.data;
}, function (response) { console.log('error:' + response.data);}
);
```

--the controller :

```
appc.module('ctrl',[])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http,mytoken,MyService) {
console.log("controller inistializing !");

MyService.getinfo(mytoken)
    .then(function (response) {
       $scope.DataList = respone.data;

    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.data)
    }
    )

.catch(function (response) {
    $window.alert('error');
});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. Also forcing Angular, well JavaScript in general, to be synchronous is the wrong pattern.

The correct thing to do would be to place the token in a Service and access it from there. Where the value returned by the service is actual a promise.

```
module.service('Authentication', function ($http, RESTUrl, $q, mytoken) {
    var tokenDeferred = $q.deferred();
    $http.get(RESTUrl +'?user=currss').then (function (response){
        tokenDeferred.resolve(response.data);
    }, function (response) {
        tokenDeferred.reject(response);
    });

    this.getToken = function() {
        return tokenDeferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Then use it like so:

```
Authentication.getToken().then(
    function(data) {
        // success function
    },function(errMsg) {
        // error function
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you that get token from backend in respose of successful login and store this token to any service variable or cookies.so before moving to dashboard,through login response, you have token stored in your app variable.